# How to insert images in DataGridView from SQL database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I m working on an application where 5 images saved on a single id in the database. Now I want to retrieve these images in a datagrigview whenever they are called. My following code is working good with picturebox but I want multiple images containing the same pincode in datagridview from SQl server database.

```
try
{
    string sql = "Select IMAGE from UserInput where PINCODE = '" + txt_LPin.Text + "'";
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        //txt_LName.Text = reader[0].ToString();
        byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[1]);

        if (img == null)
            pb_get1.Image = null;
        else
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);

            pb_get1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        txt_LPin.Text = "";
        txt_LName.Text = "";
        pb_get1.Image = null;
        MessageBox.Show("This ID does not exist.");
    }
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I have tried following code for dataGridView but it shows cross mark intead of image on place of image.

```
SqlDataAdapter adpat = new SqlDataAdapter();
adpat.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select IMAGE from UserInput", conn);
DataTable table = new DataTable("UserInput");
adpat.Fill(table);
//create image column:
DataGridViewImageColumn photoColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
photoColumn.DataPropertyName = "Picture";
photoColumn.Width = 200;
photoColumn.HeaderText = "Picture column";
photoColumn.ReadOnly = true;
photoColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(photoColumn);
//bind data to dgv:
dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
```

Comment: any code for Grid Loading u have written?

Comment: I have edited the question with the code tried for datagridview.

Answer (score 1):

**To insert images in gridview ,you can use:**

1) We need datasource:

`dataGridView1.DataSource = datasouce;`

2) create an image column by writing;

```
DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
img.Name = "img";
img.HeaderText = "Image Column";
img.ValuesAreIcons = true;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
```

3) and Finally

```
int number_of_rows = dataGridView1.RowCount;
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++)
{
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "true")
{
Icon image = Properties.Resources.succcess_icon;
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["img"].Value = image;
}
else
{
Icon image =Properties.Resources.cancel_icon;
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["img"].Value = image;
}
}
```

Comment: but where is the reference of database?

Comment: You can bind dataset (or any other datasource) with gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Solved by the following line of codes;

```
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Image,Name from UserInput where PINCODE = '" + txt_LPin.Text + "'",conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
```